# Why are there duplicate columns created after using the within function in R?

Tags: r

I am an absolute newbie to R. I'm currently trying to understand how to use within and this is one problem that I fail to understand.

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars <- within(mtcars, mtcars$mpg <- mtcars$mpg +2)
View(mtcars)
```

This code generated duplicate columns of the original data also with a new heading, except for the column "mtcars.mpg" since I altered it. I'm not too sure the answer I'm looking for since I'm still unfamiliar with R. But I would like to know why this problem occurred and how to resolve it.
[The table I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9BnA.png)

I feel this problem seem trivial to other posts that I have seen but I can't find any answers by myself.
So,I appreciate any help or additional materials that will aid me in my learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`within` function evaluates the expression given, so in your case it evaluated `mtcars$mpg <- mtcars$mpg +2` which returned a complete dataframe with a new mpg value, accordingly it appended those new column to the existing one.

That's why you have duplicate columns.

What you should be doing is something like that:

#### In case you want to overwrite mpg in mtcars:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars <- within(mtcars, mpg <- mpg + 2)
```

#### In case you want to create a new column from mpg after adding 2 to it

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars <- within(mtcars, new_mpg <- mpg + 2)
```